# ASP.NET: How to determine account login?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Can someone please point me in the right direction as to how to determine if an user is currently logged in?

I am currently using C# in Visual Studio.  It came with an default web application example.

I added a bunch of pages, I would like to set them up so they are only visible when an user is logged in already.

Comment: You'll need a login page, and then set the authorization. Here is a good example to get you on the right track: http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/role-based-authorization-cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the IsAuthenticated property on the Page.Request

HttpRequest.IsAuthenticated

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.isauthenticated.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can check his `session` to check his presence, all though it is not full proof method but it can help you if you have set session expiration time to small time like 5 min. etc..

Comment: Thanks, I will look into tutorials that teach how to use sessions.

Answer (score 0):

You should to take a look at [ASP.NET Login Controls Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Page.User Property (System.Web.UI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.user.aspx)

something like

```
if (Page.User != null) ...
```

or check a user role

```
if (Page.User.IsInRole("[YourUserRole]")) ...
```

to get started

Also this is a quick read on [ASP.NET Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291347%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)